# How to send email confirmation mail to user using asp.net mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have build an application and want to send user a confirmation email after registration.I have taken ActivationCode value by guid=new.guid(); but it don't get store in the database and after debugging I evaluate the value it says         :The name 'ActivationCode' does not exist in the current context.

```
public ActionResult Activation()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Invalid Activation code.";//This get outputted always
    if (RouteData.Values["id"] != null)
    {
        Guid activationcode = new Guid(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());
        IPHISEntities usersEntities = new IPHISEntities();
        User userActivation = usersEntities.Users.Where(p => p.ActivationCode == activationcode).FirstOrDefault();
        if (userActivation != null)//this condition gets true
        {
            usersEntities.Users.Remove(userActivation);
            try {
                usersEntities.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Activation successful.";
        }
    }

    return View();
}

private void SendActivationEmail(User user)
{
    Guid activationcode = Guid.NewGuid();
    IPHISEntities usersEntities = new IPHISEntities();
    usersEntities.Users.Add(new User
    {
        UserId = user.UserId,
       ActivationCode = activationcode
    });
    try
    {
        usersEntities.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
    using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("xyzz@gmail.com", user.EmailAddress))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
        string body = "Hello " + user.FirstName + ",";
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + string.Format("{0}://{1}/User/Activation/{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Authority, activationcode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("xyzz@gmail.com", "********");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }


//**User.cs**:
namespace ConnectionSQL_webAPI_.Models
{

    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class User
    {
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public User()
    {
        this.Answers = new HashSet<Answer>();
        this.Appointments = new HashSet<Appointment>();
        this.DoctorInfoes = new HashSet<DoctorInfo>();
        this.Payments = new HashSet<Payment>();
        this.UserLoginDetails = new HashSet<UserLoginDetail>();
    }


    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string MiddleName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public System.Guid ActivationCode { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public string UserUniqueId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> UserTypeId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<int> AddressId { get; set; }

    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }

}
```

Expected Output

> Activation Successful

Actual Output

> Invalid Activation code

Comment: I think I might have found the problem. Your adding the validation guid to the user account, then once you get the validation back your using .Remove which is trying to delete the user account. Probably not your intention. 

If for some reason the user account has any foreign key constraints or permission issue that would prevent the account from updating.

Might also check to make sure your database and entity model are up to date.

Comment: database entity model is up to date.Not having any foreign key constraints because the activation property is in the same table that of other user information (i.e User table).

Comment: Its shows no error , Output is Invalid activation code.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `Guid activationcode = new Guid(RouteData.Values["id"].ToString());`. Are you hitting that breakpoint?

Comment: `Its shows no error` Please remove your mention of `CS0103` then.

Comment: it gets when you debug and check the evaluation for activation code

Comment: Your last comment is unclear what it means, and unclear what it is replying to. Please remove the CS0103 mention from your question.

Comment: when I used debugger the code and see the actual revaluation of activationcode ,it shows the error ...The output is invalid activationcode which is displayed

Comment: What error does it show? Please don't say CS0103 - it **definitely** is not that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take ActivationCode in different table and make it uniqueidentifier in database.Now update your database in the model and check for the ActivationCode Property if it is Guid and Execute the above code.
Result Output: Activation successfull

Answer (score -1):

Add

```
using System.Runtime.Remoting;
```

Comment: But there is no `ActivationCode` in the [`System.Runtime.Remoting` namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.remoting).

Comment: I use System.Runtime.Remoting; but no difference in output

Comment: Now i have changed the ActivationCode from users table to userlogindetails tables.Still getting redline under this Guid activationcode = Guid.NewGuid(); and ActivationCode = activationcode